# sql insert into a table with computed columns

Tags: sql

I have a table with 4 columns, say COLA,COLB,COLC,COLD. COLC and COLD are computed columns.
Suppose I want to insert a row into table, should the query be something like

```
insert into Table (COLA,COLB,COLC,COLD) values (1,2,'','')?
```

I know I can't insert into computed columns. But how can I add a row and keep the default computed columns as they are?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: computed columns need not be considered in the insert statement.

Answer (score 5):

try this

```sql
    INSERT INTO TABLE (COLA,COLB) values (1,2);
```

you dont need to provide the values even blanks for computed column. They get calculated automatically

Comment: Does this work when the computed column has been defined as a not null column?

Answer (score 1):

Just specify the columns you want to insert values into:

```
insert into Table (COLA,COLB) values (1,2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just don't specify the calculated columns:

```
insert into Table (COLA,COLB) values (1,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all! I just got that out too! Previously I got errors that number of col don't match, because I missed a a column.