# How to inserted a computed column

Tags: sql

I am trying to insert to a table with values from multiply joined tables.

Here is my code:

```
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[ORD_PURCHASING_GROUP_DTL]
               ([ORG_ID]
               ,[ORG_UNIT_ID]
               ,[PURCHASING_GROUP]
              ,[MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID]
              ,[SUB_CUSTOMER_ID]
              ,[ADDOPER]
              ,[ADDDATE]
              ,[MODOPER]
              ,[MODDATE]
              ,[CONCURRENCY_ID]
              ,[EFFECTIVE_BEGIN_DATE]
              ,[EFFECTIVE_END_DATE]
              ,[LAST_FIRST_NAME]
              ,[ACTIVE_FLAG]
              ) 
    (select 'SIAM', 'SIAM', CONCAT(@conf_name, '-', demo.DEMOGRAPHIC_CODE) 
 as PURCHASING_GROUP, demo.master_customer_id, 0, 'SIAM_MTG_PG_SQL' as 
 ADDOPER, GETDATE() as ADDDATE, NULL as MODOPER, NULL as MODDATE, 0, 
 demo.USER_D1 as EFFECTIVE_BEGIN_DATE, NULL as EFFECT_END_DATE,  
 cus_addr.Last_First_Name as LAST_FIRST_NAME , cus_status.ACTIVE_FLAG as 
 ACTIVE_FLAG 
    from cus_demographic as demo
         join CUS_PRIMARY_EMPL_ADDR_MBR_VW  cus_addr on 
 demo.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID = cus_addr.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID
         join CUS_STATUS_VW cus_status  on demo.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID = 
 cus_status.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID
        where 
           1 = 1
        and demographic_code in (
           select RIGHT(pg.PURCHASING_GROUP, LEN(pg.PURCHASING_GROUP)-
 CHARINDEX('-', pg.PURCHASING_GROUP))
           FROM [ORD_PURCHASING_GROUP] as pg
              where pg.PURCHASING_GROUP like concat(@conf_name, '%') 
        )
        and demographic_subcode = @conf_name)
```

I get the error:

```
Msg 271, Level 16, State 1, Line 82
The column "LAST_FIRST_NAME" cannot be modified because it is either a 
computed column or is the result of a UNION operator.
Msg 271, Level 16, State 1, Line 82
The column "ACTIVE_FLAG" cannot be modified because it is either a computed 
column or is the result of a UNION operator.
```

I am not sure how to insert a "computed column". I say a post where it said I should alter the table. But I want to insert these values...

Here is the link... 
[How do you add a computed column to a Table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11058387/how-do-you-add-a-computed-column-to-a-table)

Comment: The whole point of a computed column is that you do not set the value in an `insert`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot insert values to computed columns but you can do this:

[sql insert into a table with computed columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22642654/sql-insert-into-a-table-with-computed-columns)